# add some of the fields of an XML together with XSLT (but not all)

Tags: xml, xslt, concatenation

I am a great noob where XSLT is concerned. I copied and pasted stuff from this forum, and it works. However, i would like to finetune. I can find examples of how to concat all fields, but nog how to concat some of the fields.

I have this XML

```
      <xs:element name="Medewerker_X">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Medewerker" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="Roepnaam" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="Voorletters" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="Voorvoegsel" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="Achternaam" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="E-mail_werk" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>

<Medewerker_X>
  <Medewerker>654654</Medewerker>
  <Roepnaam>Mark</Roepnaam>
  <Voorletters>MAB</Voorletters>
  <Achternaam>Puist</Achternaam>
  <Email>lala@test.com</Email>
</Medewerker_X>
<Medewerker_X>
  <Medewerker>084680</Medewerker>
  <Roepnaam>Maarten</Roepnaam>
  <Voorletters>M</Voorletters>
  <Voorvoegsel>ter</Voorvoegsel>
  <Achternaam>Doornemalen</Achternaam>
  <Email>sweetie@test.com</Email>
</Medewerker_X>
```

With this xslt

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/*/child::*">
<xsl:for-each select="child::*">
<xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>;</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="position()  = last()"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>    <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

it outputs this:

```
654654;Mark;MAB;Puist;lala@test.com
084680;Maarten;M;ter;Doornemalen;sweetie@test.com
```

What i would like to have is an output like this, where some of the fields are concatenated (and some others are no relevant):

```
Mark Puist;lala@test.com
Maarten ter Doornemalen;sweetie@test.com
```

Order of the fields is not relevant, additional fields can be there, i don't mind. Just as long as those two columns are present.

Can you help me?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes
This link has all the information you need.
* selects all children, A selects all A children, A|B selects A or B children.
Stop copy and pasting and start understanding.

Comment: Please post a **complete** example of the XML input.

Comment: I think you're not only a bit of a noob in terms of XSLT, but also in terms of your learning strategy. Cutting and pasting examples and asking questions on a forum if you get stuck is no way to learn a new language. Take a day out to read a good book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**

I think your input XML is like this (note that I have added a root node named `<root>`)

```
<root>
<Medewerker_X>
  <Medewerker>654654</Medewerker>
  <Roepnaam>Mark</Roepnaam>
  <Voorletters>MAB</Voorletters>
  <Achternaam>Puist</Achternaam>
  <Email>lala@test.com</Email>
</Medewerker_X>
<Medewerker_X>
  <Medewerker>084680</Medewerker>
  <Roepnaam>Maarten</Roepnaam>
  <Voorletters>M</Voorletters>
  <Voorvoegsel>ter</Voorvoegsel>
  <Achternaam>Doornemalen</Achternaam>
  <Email>sweetie@test.com</Email>
</Medewerker_X>
</root>
```

with this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- now,  we'll loop for each child `Medewerker_X` of the root node -->
        <xsl:for-each select="root/Medewerker_X">
            <!-- If position is greater than 1, add a linebreak before -->
            <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
                <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <!-- now let us do a loop of the target child elements -->
            <xsl:for-each select="*[self::Roepnaam or self::Voorvoegsel or self::Achternaam or self::Email]">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <!-- Test for the position of elements. In the input XML, 
                         `Email` is the last child element
                    -->
                    <xsl:when test="position() = last()">
                        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <!-- this tests for the 2nd to the last position -->
                    <xsl:when test="position() = last()-1">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it outputs:

```
Mark Puist;lala@test.com
Maarten ter Doornemalen;sweetie@test.com
```

Comment: I have added a root node `root`.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question?

Comment: I just assumed that his input XML contains `Medewerker_X` nodes.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joel M Lamsen, this makes my day :-)